# getting error in swapping gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i want to swap the gems with the gemcomponent only,that is invisible i tried the snippet blow ,but i'am getting nullexception error as:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
board.SwapGem () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/board.cs:81)
Gem.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/Gem.cs:59)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32, Int32)
```

what am i doing wrong ??

**board.cs**

```
public List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
    public Gem LastGem;
    public Vector3 gem1start,gem2start,gem1end,gem2end;

    public Gem gem1,gem2; // gem to change i

    public Gem gemComponent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gem1start=gem1.transform.position;
        gem1end = gemComponent.transform.position;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

                }
    }

    public void SwapGem()
    {
        gem2start = gem1start;
        gem2end = gem1end;
        gem1.transform.position = gem2start;
        gemComponent.transform.position = gem2end;

    }
```

**gem.cs**

```
public void OnMouseDown()
    {

        if (!GameObject.Find("board").GetComponent<board>().isSwapping) 
        {
              ToggleSelector ();
            GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().SwapGem ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: One of your reference variables isn't set. Possibly `gem1` or `gemComponent`. Notice the exception is thrown on line 81 (it's not clear to me which line that is, but it's easy enough for you to check). Perhaps you need to set something in the inspector, and/or look up a component when the game starts?

Comment: @ rutter thank you..,for making me understand the error..,but after sloving that i gett another problem,please help me sloving that too.. here is the link of that.." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776052/how-to-remove-add-neighbors-of-gems "